# iphone simulator deny locating

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

how can i configure the Xcode simulator to NOT localize me. i want to check my locationManagerDidFail Methode.

Answer (score 0):

Will calling the method manually from your app delegate test your functionality well enough?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is related, and the answer may help:

[Disable location service in iPhone simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333107/disable-location-service-in-iphone-simulator)